# Image uploader FileReader not working in angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6, image-upload

I'm implementing small chat application using socket.io. everything works fine.Also I have to upload image to chat and already implemented.

> **My code is working if I put break point**. (see image below)
>
> > I have added break point to 
> >      **reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);** and debug

[image]

But when I check it without break point it's not working. **reader.result** is null.

*Do I need to add sleep() some time?*

```js
onFileChanged(event) {
 
    var reader = new FileReader();   
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); 
    
    alert(reader.result );
    //chat box inputcode here
}
```

```html
<form novalidate="" #chatForm="ngForm" autocomplete="off">
    
    <a type="button"  (click)="fileInput.click()">
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i>
     </a>
   
   <input style="display: none" type="file"(change)="onFileChanged($event)" #fileInput>   
   
   <input [(ngModel)]="_sendMessage.message" name="inputMessage" type="text"(keypress)="eventHandler($event)"  />

</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have resoleve the issue. I put my own answer to help others like me :D

```js
 onFileChanged(event) {
 
    var reader = new FileReader();   
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); 
    
    reader.onload = (e) =>  {
         alert(reader.result );
        //chat box inputcode here
    }

}
```